# Getting exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities when launching browser through Selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting the above exception when IntelliJ tries to launch the Chrome browser.

I am running this code on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have already tried updating the browser and using the specific jars for ChromeDriver.

Code to launch browser:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

POM.xml:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an ancient version of Selenium (2.53.1) that is not compatible with the latest chrome driver binaries.

See the following parts of your POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The Current Java version of Selenium as of the time of writing this is 3.141.59 (Have a look at https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ to see what the latest revision is).

You need to update to a much more recent version of Selenium.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried using your method but now I am getting the following exception:


org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Comment: Looks like you now have a version of the ChromeDriver binary that is too new, you will want to download and use the ChromeDriver binary for chrome 75, see http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads specifically https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.90/. (I'm assuming that your Google Chrome version is 75.x.x)

Comment: Facing this issue even with Selenium 4.0.0. till now we've been using 3.7.1. after seeing this issue upgraded to 4.0.0, but still no luck. any other dependencies that we need to look at?

Answer (score 0):

In your pom place that as a property:

```
<properties>
    <selenium.version>3.5.3</selenium.version>
</properties>
```

Then, in each dependency where you use a selenium version, just replace by the property reference, like that:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```